# Is it better to add comments, or edit my question with responses to comments/answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question, and there has been 1 answer to my question, and some comments which could be partial answers.

After trying the suggestions, I found they did not help my issue.

I want to respond to indicate the additional things I have now tried, and the results.

Is it better to add comments, or edit my question with responses to the comments/answer that others have posted?

If I add the details to my question, should I add a comment to the comments/answer I received to indicate my question has been edited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit your question adding all the pertinent new information. You could also comment on the one answer you had asking for more ideas or something else to try. You could also reply to one of the comments if you need more information. But I would definitely update your question with the new information including what you tried and what has not worked

Comment: Yes and if you edit the question, it goes back onto the front page.  I don't think that happens with a comment.